# App consuming a lot memory when uploading multiple image to sever

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

In my app there is need to upload  multiple image to server. when we going to upload image to server ONE BY ONE or ALL IMAGE once's.

The basic problem is .

1. app consuming a lot memory when uploading  image to server.
2. memory that was consuming by app not release after uploading image.

here is code for uploading image to server. 
using simple AFNetwortking.

```
-(void) uploadImageToServerOneByOne:(int)count andImage:(UIImage*)img         {
NSMutableDictionary *parem_dict;

if (parem_dict == nil) {
    parem_dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
}

[parem_dict setObject:@"jpeg" forKey:@"extension"];
[parem_dict setObject:@706 forKey:@"order_id"];
[parem_dict setObject:@"gallary" forKey:@"image_type"];
[parem_dict setObject:@(count+1) forKey:@"count"];
[parem_dict setObject:@(1) forKey:@"product_id"];
[parem_dict setObject:@"SNAPBOOK" forKey:@"type"];

manager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 1200 ;
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"];
[manager POST:@"http://52.42.247.73:8080/anaventures/image/upload" parameters:parem_dict constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.5) name:@"file" fileName:@"filename.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

    [parem_dict removeAllObjects];
    formData = nil;

} progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
    NSLog(@"%f",uploadProgress.fractionCompleted);

} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    [MyLoader hideLoadingView];
    if (count + 1 < imageArray.count) {

        [self uploadImageToServerOneByOne:count +1 andImage:imageArray[count+1]];

    }else{

        [MyLoader hideLoadingView];

        NSLog(@" image successfully uploaded  -------- ohhhhhhhhooooooooooo!");

    }
    NSLog(@"success");

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

    [MyLoader hideLoadingView];
    NSLog(@"fail%@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the memory usage going down after the process? Also, I would recommend to see the pattern in memory usage - add some delay between each image and profile to see if memory is reclaimed back, after an image has been uploaded. That would tell you if there is a leak and in which variable.

Comment: I gone though profile but there was no memory leaks & app is not releasing memory.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to paste the screenshot of that part of profile...Ideally, there should be peak and it should go down and then there should be peak again and it shld go down...for each image (if done one at a time in loop with some delay)

Comment: solution is upload one by one image in operation queue!!. Your problem is not memory leak, upload multiple image take alot of memory ( in function UIImageJPEGRepresentation to get image data) and can crash Your app

Comment: @ABáo yes you are right , but i did it another api in which all image send at a time.  but getting same issue.

Comment: @Garry send all image at a time is same bad ideal. You need take alot of memory in same time for load image data. Better upload one by one, when the first is already completed, continue upload the second to the last. Or if You want better upload speed, try upload two or more image at same time, but not all!!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you did not use async methods to upload images.

I show you a upload image method and example:

```
Util method:
+ (void)uploadImage:(UIImage *)image withUrl:(NSString *)uploadUrl withBlock:(void (^)(NSString *))returnUrl {

UIImage *img = image;

//UIImage *com_img = [Util compressImage:img toMaxFileSize:25 * 1000];  // max is 250kb   // 50 *1000 :333759

UIImage *com_img_before = [Util imageCompressForWidth:img targetWidth:80];

UIImage *com_img = [Util compressImage:com_img_before toMaxFileSize:25 * 1000];

//NSData *dataObj = UIImagePNGRepresentation(com_img);

NSData *dataObj;
if (UIImagePNGRepresentation(com_img) == nil) {

    dataObj = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(com_img, 1);

} else {

    dataObj = UIImagePNGRepresentation(com_img);
}



NSDictionary * param1 = @{
                          @"id":@1,
                          @"imgFile":dataObj
                          };
AFHTTPSessionManager * session = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
session.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json",@"application/xml",@"text/json",@"text/javascript",@"text/html",@"text/plain",@"multipart/form-data",nil];

//url
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", BASE_URL, uploadUrl]; // uploadHeader  uploadImages

[session POST:url parameters:param1 constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {

    UIImage *img = image; // response
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);

    // schoolListItem@2x
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:data name:@"imgFile" fileName:@"imgFile.png"mimeType:@"image/png"];
} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"success+%@", responseObject);
    NSString *return_url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",responseObject[@"data"]]; //
    // pass data by block
    returnUrl(return_url);



} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"fail");
}];


}


 USAGE:

 [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
        __block int comemntCount = 0;

        NSString *url = @"prescription/uploadImages"; // the uplad url

        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        static dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore;  // sema 
        static dispatch_queue_t queue;

        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
            //queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.MyApp.task", NULL);
            queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);  
        });


        for (int i = 0; i < _selectedAssets.count; i ++) {  //_photosChooseArr

            dispatch_async(queue, ^{

                dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore,  DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
                [Util uploadImage:_selectedPhotos[i] withUrl:url withBlock:^(NSString *returnUrl) {

                    if (i == 0) {
                        files = returnUrl;
                        comemntCount ++;
                        if (comemntCount == _selectedAssets.count) {
                            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
                            [self doUploadMessageWithFiles:files];

                        }
                    }else { 

                        files = [files stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@",%@", returnUrl]];
                        comemntCount ++;

                        if (comemntCount == _selectedAssets.count) {
                            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
                            [self doUploadMessageWithFiles:files];
                            NSLog(@"i = %d, returnUrl = %@, files = %@", i, returnUrl, files);
                        }
                    }

                    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);

                }];

            });

        }



        /* 3 min after hide the hud  */
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(180.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // 60s after close the hud
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        });
```

This is my method to upload image array, and you can copy to your project to research, and I hope can help you.

Comment: I am going through this solution but only one image upload after that loop is not working  & what is  doUploadMessageWithFiles doing here.

Comment: @Garry at my project, our `javaer` designed that, when I upload a image, he will return a path for the uploaded img to me, after I upload the image array, I get many paths, and I compose the paths by "," separation，and so I get a string ,and I use the `doUploadMessageWithFiles ` to submit my info which contains the paths string.  You only upload one image? could you show me the project  on github? may I can found the issue, because I use my method upload max nine photos successed.

Comment: Send me your mail id i will send you mail. here i am going to upload up to 45 image without compressing.

Comment: @Garry liaodalin19903@126.com   If you do not compress your image I think this will take a long time, and in my method I have give a time limit seemingly.

Comment: did u got mail ? if yes please connect me on hangout.

Comment: @Garry I have got your e-mail, and you only upload one photo, the reason is you did not know the `semaphore`'s effect, and I have test the solution, I will send you the email, cheers!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124401/discussion-between-garry-and-qq726535609).

Comment: @Garry are u here？ delete the semaphore in project .and use async.maybe this can help you.i am in home.there is no mac.